# Angular Material почему md-card растягивается на весь экран и как мне указать высоту?

Tags: angularjs

Есть код карточек

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<h1>User List</h1>
<div class='md-padding' layout="row" flex>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <div class="parent" layout="column" ng-repeat="user in users" flex>
            <md-card>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="md-card-image" alt="user avatar">
                <md-card-content>
                    <h2>{{user}}</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                </md-card-content>
                <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                    <md-button>Save</md-button>
                    <md-button>View</md-button>
                </div>
            </md-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но в браузере все карточки нереально растягиваются и не красиво, как мне указать высоту? Т.к. если ввести высоту вручную, то ломается дизайн карточек(

Comment: что за `md-card`?

Comment: @Grundy https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/card

Comment: может это из-за того, что внутри директивы `md-card` лежит не только `md-card-content` но и левая не обернутая картинка? а, не, увидел второй пример

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое)) помогло)

Comment: о_О что помогло?

Comment: @Grundy я переместил img внутрь `md-card-content` и это помогло)) теперь буду дальше разбираться))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42990/discussion-between-grundy-and-vorobey-a).